# How can I remove a tag?

Tags: discusión, faq, etiquetas, reetiquetado

In [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18620/13418) the OP has accidentally created the tag [vocabuary](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabuary) which is both misspelt and in English.

Please can a moderator remove this? In general, how can I remove a tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks a lot for reporting this. Luckily, [your suggested edit](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/11897) removing this tag is all we have to do, since tags with 0 questions are removed automatically.

From: [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or “zombie”) tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/209901)

> Tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed at 03:00 UTC every day.
>
> Tags which are misspelled should have the questions under them retagged to the appropriate tag, which will result in its destruction due to having no uses.